# STM32 Toggle PIN when target halted

Tags: stm32, stm32f7

I am using the STM32F7 series of microcontrollers and it would be most helpful to have some GPIO change value (either toggle, pulse, high-z, ...) whenever the core is halted by the debugger attached to the JTAG interface. Is anyone aware of such a feature?

Comment: IMO it cannot be done as stopping the core should not change state of the uC. Maybe some probes have a pin which signals it - but I do not know.

Answer (score 2):

There are the `DBGMCU` registers, which can selectively stop certain peripherals (mostly timers) when the core is stopped.

The idea is to somehow make a timer output a low level signal while it's running, and high level when it isn't. A single timer can't do that, but it's possible with two timers in a master-slave configuration.

Configure `TIM3` to output a PWM signal with a very high duty cycle, starting low for two cycles, then going high for the rest of it's 65536 cycles long period. Slave it to `TIM2`, which runs with a period of 2 cycles, and resets `TIM3` on counter overflow. Thus, `TIM3` is forced permamently low as long as `TIM2` is running, but it will output a 99.997% high PWM signal when `TIM2` is stopped. Then `TIM2` is configured to stop when the core is halted by the debugger, but `TIM3` keeps running.

```
RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOBEN; // enable peripheral clocks, that might be different on your board
RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN | RCC_APB1ENR_TIM3EN;

// consult your datasheet for the right AF value
GPIOB->AFR[0] = (GPIOB->AFR[0] & ~GPIO_AFRL_AFRL0) | 2; // set PB0 to Alternate Function 2, TIM3
GPIOB->MODER = (GPIOB->MODER & ~GPIO_MODER_MODER0) | GPIO_MODER_MODER0_1; // set PB0 to Alternate Function

DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM2_STOP; // stop TIM2 when core is stopped
DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM3_STOP; // but don't stop TIM3

TIM2->ARR = 1;                  // master timer period
TIM2->CR2 = TIM_CR2_MMS_1;      // master mode selection MMS=010 Update event
TIM2->CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN;        // enable timer 2

TIM3->ARR = 65535;              // PWM period
TIM3->CCR3 = 2;                 // channel 3 PWM duty cycle
TIM3->CCMR2 = TIM_CCMR2_OC3M;   // set channel 3 to PWM mode 2
TIM3->CCER = TIM_CCER_CC3E      // enable channel 3 compare output
        /* | TIM_CCER_CC3P */;  // it's possible to invert output polarity
TIM3->SMCR = TIM_SMCR_TS_0      // trigger selection TS=001 ITR1 = TIM2 is master
        | TIM_SMCR_SMS_2;       // slave mode SMS=100 reset mode
TIM3->CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN;        // enable timer 3
```

I don't have an F7, it runs on my `STM32L151` board that happens to have a LED on PB0, which is `TIM3` channel 3. The LED is lighting up nicely when I hit the suspend button in the debugger, the low pulse is not noticeable to the naked eye at all. Apply an external [low pass RC filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#RC_filter) to make it disappear when it bothers whatever component it's connected to. It might be possible to output a clean signal using the Retriggerable one pulse mode of the advanced timers `TIM1` or `TIM8`, but I don't have any experience with these.

Comment: two timers for this task (including the precious 32 bit tim2), That is the overkill.

Comment: It would of course work with any possible master-slave timer pair.

Comment: But I do not understand what for? For stopping another micros in the multiprocessor environment jtag has special mechanisms

Comment: Maybe it's some dumb component that that would get too hot, or move too far, when the controller can't monitor it.

Comment: It would be possible to use only one timer that permantly toggles a pin and stops toggling when the core is stopped. If static levels are required, this could be accomplished by adding a simple passive capacitive differentiator and a rectifier.